# Angular2 pass outer attributes to inner contents

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I have a custom directive as below

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-textfield' ,
  template: `
    <div>
      <label floating>{{label}}</label>
      <input type="text"></input>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class TextFieldInput{
    @Input label:string;
}
```

How can I achieve the following whereby my attributes such as `[(ngModel)]` is passed on to the input text field of my custom directive?

```
<my-textfield label="Name" [(ngModel)]="user.name" ></my-textfield>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add an

```
[(ngModel)]="whatever"
```

to the input field of your custom directive, like that :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-textfield' ,
  template: `
    <div>
      <label floating>{{label}}</label>
      <input [(ngModel)]="whatever" type="text"></input>
    </div>
  `,
})

export class TextFieldInput{
    @Input label:string;
    @Input whatever:string
}
```

and use it in the parent component as

```
<my-textfield label="Name" [whatever]="user.name" ></my-textfield>
```

It's not exactly what your question implies, but for the example you provided, it has the same effect. Implementing ngModel logic to custom directives is quite more complicated.

Comment: Thanks. But I've already tried this. this will not totally work as the 2-way binding will not work on the custom component

Comment: Then, your answer is in this post:

http://almerosteyn.com/2016/04/linkup-custom-control-to-ngcontrol-ngmodel

It also includes a plunker to check it.